# ElasticSearch Logstash template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to index the SMTP receive log of my Exchange Server with ElasticSearch. So I created a logstash config file and it works very well but all of my fields are strings instead ip for source and target server for example. So I tried to change the default mapping in the logstash template:

1. I run the command `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash?pretty > C:\temp\logstashTemplate.txt`
2. Edit the textfile and add my 'SourceIP' field

   ```
   {
   "template": "logstash-*",
   "settings": {
       "index": {
           "refresh_interval": "5s"
       }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "_default_": {
           "dynamic_templates": [{
               "message_field": {
                   "mapping": {
                       "fielddata": {
                           "format": "disabled"
                       },
                       "index": "analyzed",
                       "omit_norms": true,
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "match_mapping_type": "string",
                   "match": "message"
               }
           }, {
               "string_fields": {
                   "mapping": {
                       "fielddata": {
                           "format": "disabled"
                       },
                       "index": "analyzed",
                       "omit_norms": true,
                       "type": "string",
                       "fields": {
                           "raw": {
                               "ignore_above": 256,
                               "index": "not_analyzed",
                               "type": "string"
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   "match_mapping_type": "string",
                   "match": "*"
               }
           }],
           "_all": {
               "omit_norms": true,
               "enabled": true
           },
           "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                   "type": "date"
               },
               "geoip": {
                   "dynamic": true,
                   "properties": {
                       "ip": {
                           "type": "ip"
                       },
                       "latitude": {
                           "type": "float"
                       },
                       "location": {


                           "type": "geo_point"
                       },
                       "longitude": {
                           "type": "float"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "@version": {
                   "index": "not_analyzed",
                   "type": "string"
               },
               "SourceIP": {
                   "type": "ip"
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "aliases": {}
   }
   ```
3. I uploaded the edited template with the command `curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_t
   emplate/logstash -d@C:\temp\logstash.template`
4. Restart the ElasticSearch server and index deleted/re-created

The 'SourceIP' field did not changed to type ip. What do I wrong? Can you please give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: The curl command should be `curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash --data-binary "@C:\temp\logstash.template"`, i.e. `--data-binary` instead of `-d`

Comment: @Val: Sorry, but it does not fix the issue. I can see the 'SourceIP' field in the template with curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash?pretty but if I delete the index and re-create it with kibana, the field is a string type.